# What is the spectrum of $\begin{pmatrix}0 & A \\ A^\dagger & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, I am interested in the spectrum $\{\Lambda_j\}$ of the block matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & A \\ A^\dagger & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Assuming I know the spectrum $\{\lambda_j\}$ of $A$, is there a simple expression for the spectrum of this?

I am interested in the case when $[A,A^\dagger] \neq 0$ but if there is a simple result when $[A,A^\dagger]=0$ that is also of interest.

*Attempts: I have played around with the simple $4x4$ case in Mathematica, leading me to believe in general there is no simple expression for the spectrum $\{\Lambda_j\}$ in terms of $\{\lambda_j\}$, but I'm hoping I'm wrong.*

*Edit: $A^\dagger = A^*$ is the conjugate transpose.*

Comment: This is problem 2.6.P31 from Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis 2nd edition. There, the exercise is to first show that your matrix $\mathcal{A} = \begin{pmatrix}0&A\\A^\dagger&0\end{pmatrix}$ is unitarily similar to $\begin{pmatrix}0&\Sigma\\\Sigma^T &0\end{pmatrix}$, where $A = V\Sigma W^\dagger$ is the SVD, $\Sigma = \operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n).$ Finally, one is to show that the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{A}$ are $\pm\sigma_1,\ldots\pm\sigma_n$.

Comment: please write out your matrix squared, then to the 3rd power then to the 4th power.  You should see a pattern

Comment: @D Presumably, you are using $A^\dagger$ to refer to the conjugate transpose. This convention is not universal in mathematics, so please clarify whether this is the case.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes-- physics notation. Clarified.

Comment: @Dwagg I appreciate it. By the way, are you only interested in the case that $A$ is square? For the more general case, we get essentially the same result but there are some extra zeros to manipulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A = U\Sigma V^\dagger$, then
$$
\pmatrix{0 & A\\A^\dagger & 0} = \pmatrix{U\\ & V} \pmatrix{0 & \Sigma\\ \Sigma^\dagger & 0} \pmatrix{U\\ & V}^\dagger.
$$

Comment: Thanks. To finish: the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Sigma \\ \Sigma^\dagger & 0\end{pmatrix}$ are then $\{\pm \sigma_i\}$ where $\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots, \sigma_n)$.